# Create object from constant class attribute

Tags: php, constructor, attributes, php-5.6

I would like to create a new object from the constant attribute of a class. This works like a charm if i do it in two steps, but i would like to short the lines 9 & 10 in one.

How can I tell PHP to use the attribute as a class name?

```php
class Foo{
    const CLASSNAME = 'Foo';

    function bar(){
        echo "Foobar!\n";
    }
}

// Works
$foobar = Foo::CLASSNAME;
$foo = new $foobar();

// Dont work
$foo = new Foo::CLASSNAME();

$foo->bar();
```

Comment: `$foo = (new ReflectionClass(Foo::CLASSNAME))->newInstance();` would  work. Though I *smell* namespace issues ahead. Also, you might reconsider this approach. I'd say most people reading `$foo = new Foo::CLASSNAME();` will expect a new object of `Foo`, though it really could be anything. And thus could lead to all kinds of strange behavior.

Comment: @Yoshi It should be possible to use the default class-Constant. E.g. $foo = (new ReflectionClass(Foo::class))->newInstance(); . No need of a constant. But not sure.

Comment: @Oliver I guess so. But I don't have v5.6 running anymore, and to be honest, I've forgotten when `::class` was implemented ;P If it's available in v5.6, it would at least resolve the namespace issue.

Comment: @Yoshi yeah, just like me. PHP7 is running on all my mashines now.